# Model save update only specific fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to write a webservice which performs inserts or updates.
The request is a post with headers,value which contains table name, column name and the value to be set for each column, I'm parsing the request headers and forming a parameter dict

```
def handel_request(request): if request.method == "POST":
        param_dict = formParmDict(request)
        ##if insert param_dict["Model"] is {'pk':1,'field1':100,'field2':200}
        ##if update param_dict["Model"] is {'pk':1,'field1':100}
        Model(**param_dict["Model"]).save() ## if update then sets field2 to null
        return HttpResponse()
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

This works fine while the `.save()` performs an insert.
In case of update ie if `param_dict["Model"]` contains `{pk:1, field1:somevalue}` to be updated then it sets the rest of the fields other than the ones specified in `param_dict["Model"]` to null. why is that? am I doing something wrong? isn't save suppose to update only the fields specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **not** how you're supposed to update.

```
Model(**param_dict["Model"]).save()
```

You're creating a new instance with the same `id`. Instead, you should `get` the instance, and then update it appropriately.

```
m = Model.objects.get(id=param_dict['id'])
m.field = param_dict['some_field']
m.save()
```

Or, you can use the Manager [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) method:

```
Model.objects.filter(id=param_dict['id']).update(**param_dict['Model'])
```

There's also the [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) method if you're not sure whether or not the record already exists.

You can try using a REST framework, like [tasty-pie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [django-rest-framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/), which might alleviate some problems you're having.

Edit:

A [brief summary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert) about how `save` works in django. This is what I meant about whether or not an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE` is happening. Unless your `post_data` dict contains empty values for all the fields, read the documentation on how `save` works for a more thorough understanding of how django works.

So, what is happening in your case is this:

```
dict = {'id': 1, 'field1': 'my_value'}
m = Model(**dict)
m.id       # 1
m.field1   # my_value
m.field2   # None (because you haven't set it, it defaults to None
m.save()   # UPDATEs the existing instance with id 1 with ALL of the values of `m`
```

So, you're saving an instance that contains `None` values. That's why I'm suggesting you do a `get`, so that all the correct values are filled, before saving to the database.

Comment: `save()` is not creating when the `pk` already exists in the database the record is getting updated, the unspecified fields are getting updated to null, that's the problem. I can't use django model forms its not a ui interface. Read the first few lines of the question.. its like a webservice.

Comment: No, the fields are not getting updated to null. You're creating a new instance with null values in the other fields. If you want to change only a sub-set of fields, you must either retrieve the instance with a get, update the fields, then call `save`, or use the `update` method like my answer suggests.

Comment: I tried it mate, the record is getting updated, unspecified fields are getting updated to null. I can use your answer but I cant understand why the save method is updating the unspecified field to null.

Comment: @Pannu, I'll update my answer with more of an explanation in a moment.

Comment: @Pannu, found django documentation that explains it better than I could. If you're still having trouble, let me know, and I'll try to fill in any gaps.

Comment: ahh!! now I get it!!.. sorry for the troubles mate!! I guess thats why django came up with this in 1.5 [update_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#specifying-which-fields-to-save)

Comment: @Pannu I was sure there was an `update_fields` argument to save, but I must have been looking at the old documentation. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shoul use some function like this:

```
def insert_or_update(param_dict):
    pk = param_dict.get('pk', None)
    if pk:
        Model.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(**param_dict)
    else:
        Model(**param_dict)
        Model.save()
```